# How can I use Knockoutjs "with" context and update only one bound value?

Tags: knockout.js

I can easily update all the values but if I want update only one targeted value it clears the others.

In my code snippet you can uncomment the line below to see my problem.

```
self.mainform({"AdultCount" : "test"});
```

On setting up the embedded code snippet I see that it is returning a script error but I am unsure why this is the happening.

Could you please point out what is not correct in my approach?

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
      var self = this;
    
      self.mainform = ko.observable(new FormModel());
      
      //self.mainform({"AdultCount" : "test"});
    };
    
    var FormModel = function() {
      var self = this;
    
      self.AdultCount    = ko.observable("2"); 
      self.PG1FName     = ko.observable("PG1FName");
      self.PG1LName     = ko.observable("PG1LName");
    }
    
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<form data-bind ="with: mainform">
  <input data-bind = "value: AdultCount">
  <input data-bind = "value: PG1FName">
  <input data-bind = "value: PG1LName">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it changes my targeted value but clears the rest."? I don't see any values getting cleared

Comment: In the code snippet I have a commented out line that will change the value of AdultCount and clears the other two values. I'll edit my text to be more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the entire FormModel with a new object, and the new object doesn't have those other two fields so they'll be blank, and also throw script errors because knockout can't bind to something that doesn't exist.

In order to change the value of a single property within your FormModel you need to access that property. You probably want something like this:

```
//self.mainform({"AdultCount" : "test"});
self.mainform().AdultCount("test");
```

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
      var self = this;
    
      self.mainform = ko.observable(new FormModel());
      
      self.mainform().AdultCount("test");
    };
    
    var FormModel = function() {
      var self = this;
    
      self.AdultCount    = ko.observable("2"); 
      self.PG1FName     = ko.observable("PG1FName");
      self.PG1LName     = ko.observable("PG1LName");
    }
    
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<form data-bind ="with: mainform">
  <input data-bind = "value: AdultCount">
  <input data-bind = "value: PG1FName">
  <input data-bind = "value: PG1LName">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried so many variations of syntax but I never added brackets to mainform.